# How to close a floated developer tools on Mac

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have the developer tools floated to be a separate window. 
It nows takes the entire screen.
I did lots of research to see how to close it, but found nothing related.
Most of the posts are about how to open it.
(I tried CMD + option + i / F12, neither one works).

Also, I wonder how to dock it back into the page. I do not see such 
an option under the "..." on top right corner.

Comment: FYI in the DevTools docs we refer to the "floated" position as "undocked".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Windows, Linux) restores the DevTools window back to whatever position you had it in before you undocked it.

You can also change the docking position by opening the [Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#command-menu), typing `Dock`, and selecting the option you want.

[image: Docking options in Command Menu]

You can also access these options from DevTools's Main Menu. Note: It sounds like you were looking for the options in Chrome's main menu. You won't find any DevTools options there, other than the option to open DevTools.

[image: Docking options in DevTools's Main Menu]